# CSS3 Scale Animation Keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

having a few issues using css3 animation scale, opacity and other things work but cant seem to get scale to work.

snippet:

```css
    #treeLeaves {
        background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/72/c0/8e/72c08eefa235ae1c8aa72caa71eeba39.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        width:100%;
        height:375px;
        z-index:5;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:140px;
        left:0px;
    }

    @keyframe leaves {
        0% {
            transform: scale(1.0);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(2.0);
            -webkit-transform: scale(2.0);
        }
    }

    #treeLeaves {
        animation: leaves 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
        -webkit-animation: leaves 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    }
```

```html
<div id="treeLeaves"></div>
<div class="leaves">
```

basically its 1 img that i wanted to scale up and down constantly over time.
only using webkit because it only needs to work in chrome.

thanks.

Comment: try `@-webkit-keyframes leaves`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you forgot the '`s`' in keyframes.
try `@keyframes` and `@-webkit-keyframes`.

Answer (score 13):

You just missed `s` in `keyframes` keyword.

```
@keyframes leaves {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(2.0);
    }
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sag89z72/)

Comment: Your "Working demo" doesn't work on Firefox or Edge.

Comment: @DrupalFever, Please check now. Linked image URL was outdated.